# python stop threading that are running

Tags: python, multithreading

I know this question is asked a lot of time but i am still like to know.

```
def startMonitor(self,event):       
    selectedInterface = self.interfaces_cblist.GetValue()
    Publisher().sendMessage(("test"),selectedInterface) 
    self.Close()
    selectInterfaceStr = str(selectedInterface) 
    if len(selectedInterface) == 0:
        noSelect_error = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Please select an interface","",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
        noSelect_error.ShowModal()
    else:       
        monitorStarted = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Monitor on %s started"%selectInterfaceStr,"",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
        monitorStarted.ShowModal()
        self.monitorInterface_button.Disable()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.camtableDetection,(selectInterfaceStr,))
        thread.start_new_thread(self.dhcpexhaustion,(selectInterfaceStr,))
```

how can i stop the threading?

Comment: This might be of help: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a stop method that assigns to a variable such as **self.abort**. Than, in the function you are threading, you should check for this variable regularly and stop the function(with **return** or something similar). Here's an example class that uses this technique for stopping the thread.

```
class PymineLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('server.log', 'a')
        self.abort = False
        self.log_queue = Queue.Queue()
        threading.Thread(target=self.process_queue, args=()).start()

    def error(self, i):
        line = u'[%s] [ERROR] %s' % (str(time.time()), i)
        self.log_queue.put(line)

    def info(self, i):
        line = u'[%s] [INFO] %s' % (str(time.time()), i)
        self.log_queue.put(line)

    def process_queue(self):
        while not self.abort:
            try:
                log_line = self.log_queue.get(timeout=1)
                print log_line
                self.file.write("%s\n" % log_line)
                self.file.flush()
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

    def stop(self):
        self.abort = True
```

The **stop** method assigns the variable **self.abort**, which gets regularly checked by the thread.

*Class source: pymine2 project*

Comment: do you know how i could do it with wxpython instead? where to trigger the self.abort

Comment: @ku1918 I've never used wxPython before. So I have no idea.